# Why can't select one object in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm creating a ecommerce store using django And tried s many things to do this.index page is working pretty well but I want select specific product when I click .ex: when I click a shoe I want to enter shoe detail page with shoe image and all the necessary details.Here is my home page.And also I highly recommend to check my all code because you can't get any idea with only this code.github [source code here](https://github.com/dtheekshanalinux/django_web_store).thanks dinindu

```
{% extends 'store/main.html'%}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<style>
img:hover{
opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
<div class="row">
{% for product in products %}
<div class="col-lg-4">
<a href="{% url 'productDetail' Product.name %}"><img
class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}"></a>
<div class="box-element product">
<h6><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h6>
<hr>
<button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add"
class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to
Cart</button>
<h4 style="display: inline-block; float:
right"><strong>Rs {{product.price}}</strong></h4>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and have a look at [ask]. Giving a link to your complete source code is **not** how you ask a question you are supposed to provide a _[mre]_ in your question. Currently your question doesn't make much sense, please [edit] it and add a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this, an adapt it to your project:

Views:

```
def product_list(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'list.html',{'products': products})


def product_detail(request, id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'detail.html',{'product': product,})
```

urls:

```
    path('products/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('products/<int:id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail')
```

templates

list.html

```
    {% for product in products %}
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
        <img src="{ product.image.url }}">
        </a>
        <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

detail.html

```
    <div>
        <img src="{{ product.image.url }}">
        <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
        <h3>{{ product.price }}</h3>
        <h4>{{ product.digital }}</h4>
    </div>
```